# Possible pitfalls of this asynchronous garbage collector

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, concurrency, garbage-collection, nonblocking

I've been studying a little about garbage collection, mostly applied to server-side / real-time applications, and I've started to sketch an algorithm with which it would be possible to have an asynchronous garbage collection system. Since I'm starting on this topic now, so I don't know very deeply about gc algorithms, I was wondering about the possible pitfalls of an implementation like that. The algorithm is very crude, and with many undefined parts.

Here's how I thought about it:

- each thread has its own heap space to manage, and stores a list of pointers it owns that are in use by other threads
  With that, garbage collection works totally asynchronous to the running threads, and:
- phase 1 start following the threads' roots and marking all objects reacheable by them. If we get into another thread's space, we stop following this pointer, and mark this pointer as "in use" on the owner thread
- after we have marked all regions, we select a region (maybe with most dead references as possible), and start copying its live object references to another space. (it might be the whole thread heap space, but I think it could be too memory-intensive this operation)
- copying starts with setting with CAS a flag which states that the object is being copied. Any mutable action to be performed on this particular object while that flag is set will spin lock until a new address is set by the gc thread. When copying finishes, a new address is set on the old one, and any mutable reference to be performed on the object will be routed to the new object
- after updating all references made to those pointers using CAS, the old space is finally freed (no new pointers will be updated with the wrong address, since every mutator will first check to see if the reference has changed locations)

That's it!

Anyway, I'm quite excited with a possible implementation that doesn't stops-the-world, and using only fast spin-locks that apply only to the object being copied. But I'd like to know if this is possible to implement, or if there is any possibility of having a dangling pointer somewhere, or memory leaks, or it it's inneficient, etc. Any info that will contribute to this will be greatly appreciated!

I'm not at all too sure about how e.g. it would handle circular references from different threads. I think this would be handled naturally since we update all hazard pointers the current gc'ed thread has.
There might also be some kind of concurrent access I wasn't considering.

Thank you!

---- EDIT:
Thanks to Ernest's contribution, I'm thinking about not using a copying algorithm, but maybe a simple mark & sweep. That's because we'd need to check every time we access an object's variable if the pointer has been updated. This seems to me a quite big overhead. Doesn't it?

Comment: What's the question? What's this apply to? .NET or something else?

Comment: No, sorry if I wasn't very clear (or wasn't very precise). This applies more generally to a garbage collection algorithm that could be implemented to work in a vm or something like that. The question is: what are its possible flaws?

Comment: in my case, I'm thinking about implementing a compiler from a language to C code, and it would need garbage collection!

Comment: Waneck you will need some form of a software read barrier.

Comment: Thank you. You are right, I'd really need a read barrier. That's really the worst problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Waneck, regarding the overhead, no it's not so big. You can look at the original paper/draft of the pauseless GC.http://www.usenix.org/events/vee05/full_papers/p46-click.pdf there is real implementation now, the read barrier is few instructions but indeed you need 'em before each load. You can simplify the barrier as proposed by Dave Moon http://www.azulsystems.com/blog/cliff/2011-02-17-fosdem-brussels-and-new-blog-software#comment-2168 Also the blog itself it's an outstanding source of ideas...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ideas are good but I believe there are lots of subtle problems that will require a lot of work to solve and, once solved, you won't be able to attain competitive throughput performance.

> each thread has its own heap space to manage, and stores a list of pointers it owns that are in use by other threads With that, garbage collection works totally asynchronous to the running threads, and:

If there is a shared object, which thread owns it? If a concurrent collection has objects added to it from different threads, will there be many inter-heap pointers? How do you handle cycles between heaps?

> phase 1 start following the threads' roots and marking all objects reacheable by them. If we get into another thread's space, we stop following this pointer, and mark this pointer as "in use" on the owner thread

If this is done concurrently with the mutator running, how do you prevent race conditions where the mutators alter the topology to introduce or eliminate inter-heap references while the GC is doing this marking?

> after we have marked all regions, we select a region (maybe with most dead references as possible), and start copying its live object references to another space. (it might be the whole thread heap space, but I think it could be too memory-intensive this operation)

If this is for multicore, copying will saturate global memory bandwidth and destroy scalability.

> copying starts with setting with CAS a flag which states that the object is being copied. Any mutable action to be performed on this particular object while that flag is set will spin lock until a new address is set by the gc thread. When copying finishes, a new address is set on the old one, and any mutable reference to be performed on the object will be routed to the new object

Lock-free is tricky. You're making assumptions about memory models. You may need memory barriers. Looks like you're just emulating a lock, in which case you're talking about acquiring and releasing a lock around every write of a reference into the heap which would be prohibitively expensive.

Spin locks are also bad for concurrency because you're not only tying up a thread but also burning a core that can no longer do the work that you are waiting on! See the [last core slowdown](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/3553) bug in GHC. A wait free solution would use CAS to get the mutator thread to help with the GC work rather than block waiting for another thread to do it.

> after updating all references made to those pointers using CAS, the old space is finally freed (no new pointers will be updated with the wrong address, since every mutator will first check to see if the reference has changed locations)

Ok.

Comment: Thank you for your very valuable insights! 
I asked this some time ago and looking now I really see that this way to deal with them has many problems, specially with the concurrent marking (wouldn't really work). 
But answering your questions: 
- I think the ownership of an object is quite easy to make, the thread that created an object will own it. If the object is shared, it means that it will be marked in that "external reference" list, which I still think it's a good idea ;)

Comment: - The spin lock would be quick enough (just enough time to copy the object) to not be prohibitive, I think. Of course special care would have to be taken for big objects, but that's always the case for copying gc's anyway :)

Comment: Why would copying saturate global memory bandwidth?

Answer (score 1):

The major issue I see is synchronization. You need memory barriers to ensure that the various threads see up-to-date data on each other's heaps, and I don't see really where those would go and still maintain your fully asynchronous operational model.

Comment: Do you mean after an object is copied, all old references will still see an outdated version? Would checking to see if the object pointer has been updated be a performance hit?

Answer (score 1):

Just saw this recently http://java-monitor.com/forum/showthread.php?t=890

As far as I understand you are talking about model similar to what is used by Erlang VM - each threads has its own heap. It is possible by Erlang nature - no spin locks are required (at least for the thread heap).

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know how erlang's gc works, but I guess I'm looking for pretty much the same requirements. The problem is that erlang can achieve that without much problems and spin locks because everything is immutable, so no worries about not having the most updated version / or changing pointers' location. I'd still have to deal with them ; )

Comment: To Waneck: I'd rather focus on making GC itself running faster. Stop-the-world GC's are simple and predictable. In principle incremental GC is an attempt to move in that direction.

Comment: And yet... Another vector of solving heap problems is to make language/VM by itself less memory greedy.

For example in my TIScript there is a feature named multi-returns. Say you need to return rectangle (x,y,w,h) from function.
In Javas you will do it as:
`Rectangle r = wdg.getRect(); // does new Rectangle()...`
but it is more effective to do it as:
`var (x,y,w,h) = wdg.getRect(); // returns four values on stack`
And no GC needed.

Comment: yes, you are right about this, they are safer. I'm looking for two areas, though, that would benefit from having a non-pausing gc. Of course there are other ways out, and I might even follow another direction later on. But for now I just can't seem to find a good reason that this kind of algorithm would be bad. And the true power of this, I think, is that it won't pause the application, ever.

Comment: I was thinking about a copying gc, though, and it does seem to bring much more hassle than it's worth. Maybe something on the line of Immix (http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1375581.1375586 ) would be nicer, specially to avoid all that changing pointer confusion (that Ernest pointed out!)